# Get Quantile values from geom_boxplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm using ggplot2 function geom_boxplot() to create boxplots of my data.

Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844845/how-do-i-turn-the-numeric-output-of-boxplot-with-plot-false-into-something-usa) question, I'd like to get the quantile values used for the creation of the boxplot, e.g., in a matrix.
Is there a way to print out the values used within geom_boxplot()?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use an outside of `ggplot` aggregate, but here's how to do it with `ggplot`, using the function `ggplot_build` on a created plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=mpg)) + geom_boxplot() 
ggplot_build(p)$data

[[1]]
  ymin lower middle  upper ymax outliers notchupper notchlower x PANEL group weight ymin_final ymax_final
1 10.4  14.5   15.5 18.400 21.5            17.09102   13.90898 1     1     1      1       10.4       21.5
2 17.8  21.0   22.8 28.075 33.9            26.02695   19.57305 2     1     2      1       17.8       33.9
3 15.0  15.8   19.7 26.000 30.4            26.90729   12.49271 3     1     3      1       15.0       30.4
   xmin  xmax
1 0.625 1.375
2 1.625 2.375
3 2.625 3.375
```

Comment: a bit unrelated but if there are several of boxplots e.g. [[1]] , [[2]] .. etc, is there a way to collect this all in a dataframe and save to csv?